# How to use Google Play Service API Client for Activity Recognition

Tags: android, google-play-services, activity-recognition

I want to detect whether I am walking using Google's Play Service Api Client for Activity Recognition. I have read several post on the internet (include stack overflow) about this topic but I still cannot understand how to use the API.

I want to know what is the simplest code to detect whether I am walking or not. And I see this webpage: https://tsicilian.wordpress.com/2013/09/23/android-activity-recognition/

with these code

```
 * Called when a new activity detection update is available.
 */
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
     //...
      // If the intent contains an update
    if (ActivityRecognitionResult.hasResult(intent)) {
        // Get the update
        ActivityRecognitionResult result = 
          ActivityRecognitionResult.extractResult(intent);

         DetectedActivity mostProbableActivity 
                = result.getMostProbableActivity();

         // Get the confidence % (probability)
        int confidence = mostProbableActivity.getConfidence();

        // Get the type 
        int activityType = mostProbableActivity.getType();
       /* types:
        * DetectedActivity.IN_VEHICLE
        * DetectedActivity.ON_BICYCLE
        * DetectedActivity.ON_FOOT
        * DetectedActivity.STILL
        * DetectedActivity.UNKNOWN
        * DetectedActivity.TILTING
        */
        // process
    }
```

i just want the result from getMostProbableActivity() but I don't know how to get it. Where should these code be placed, what I need to do besides these codes (for example what do i need to initialise before this, do I need to implement other class? is these code in the mainActivity?)

i can't understand the Google documentation and any tutorial on the web because i Can't comprehend them (maybe it's because they are too high level).

I really appreciate answers to this. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Actually there is a sample app by Google https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/ActivityRecognition

You need to requestActivityUpdates e.g., from your activity

```
googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addApi(ActivityRecognition.API)
        .build();

googleApiClient.connect();

Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourService.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

ActivityRecognition.ActivityRecognitionApi.requestActivityUpdates(
            googleApiClient,
            1000 /* detection interval */,
            pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The sample app by google is too hard and I don't know what is going on. I don't even know what your code is doing, especially this 3 lines:

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourService.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

ActivityRecognition.ActivityRecognitionApi.requestActivityUpdates(
            googleApiClient,
            1000 /* detection interval */,
            pendingIntent);

Comment: Can you please explain?

Comment: ActivityRecognition is done asynchrnously, and you need two code fragmetn - one for request and one for receiving result. The code snnipet in my answer is for requesting ActivityRecognition. You can put this code whereever you want to request ActivityRecognition. e.g., inside onCreate of your activity.
Code for receiving result (something in your question) is live in your service class. Also make sure you declare the service in your AndroidManifest.xml